# Turning on turbolink

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

After I've precompiled assets and uploaded them to CDN I decided to turn on turbolinks. They were kind of turned on before when I were precompiling assets, that is I had `gem turbolinks` in Gemfile and `require turbolinks` in `application.js` but in `application.html` I had `data-no-turbolink` instead of `data-turbolinks-track" => true`.

Now I change it to `data-no-turbolink` to `data-turbolinks-track" => true` and expect them to work in **production** on the my local machine but it seems they aren't. Visually it seems they aren't working and "initiator" in the browser isn't turbolinks.

I don't want to recompile the assets if it's not really needed because reuploading them to CDN takes a lot of time.

So do I have to recompile them? Or perhaps I just don't notice that they are really working already?

Answer (score 1):

`data-turbolinks-track` is only for asset tracking (to make sure the loaded assets file is the latest). It does not affect whether Turbolinks is used for a particular link.

If turbolinks is installed, any internal link *without* `data-no-turbolink` will be loaded using Turbolinks UJS.

The following code will fire an alert if Turbolinks is running.

```
$(document).on('page:load', function(){ alert("Turbolinks is active"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not easy with the sparse information you provide. But here are some notes worth considering:

About [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks):

> With Turbolinks pages will change without a full reload, so you can't
>   rely on DOMContentLoaded or jQuery.ready() to trigger your code.
>   Instead Turbolinks fires events on document to provide hooks into the
>   lifecycle of the page.

You probably use jQuery? Read above link to understand. A good solution is this one: [jQuery.turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks)

> ...
>   But if you have a large codebase with lots of $(el).bind(...)
>   Turbolinks will surprise you. Most part of your JavaScripts will stop
>   working in usual way. It's because the nodes on which you bind events
>   no longer exist.
>   ...

Comment: Turbolinks will request a full page, then swap out the content with JS. The network traffic should look the same.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I corrected it. I mistakenly thought it improved network traffic when I tested it with my site, but I did not look close. My bad.